# Converting the file of decimal values into hex format

Tags: python, hex

I am new to python and I am trying to write a simple script that will convert each row of my .txt file containing decimals into hex format and will save it into another .txt file. My input has the 16 bit values in decimal format such as

15166

46818

26814

640

44756

27831

2646

This is a snippet that I have so far:

```
import binascii 
filename = '1.txt' 
content = f.read() 
out = binascii.hexlify(content)

f = open('out.txt', 'wb')
f.write(out)
f.close()
```

This is the output that I am getting 31353136360d0a34363831380d0a32363831340d0a3634300d0a34343735360d0a32373833310d0a323634360d0a393237360d0a323238390d0a333330320d0a33393137370d0a393535340d0a363239310d0a31353438310d0a33353632300d0a35373330310d0a33323933350d0a3834380d0a34313639330d0a33353538340d0a31363936390d0a31313539300d0a31343639350d0a36333931350d0a393238340d0a33323339370d0a343235330d0a33323934320d0a31303139340d0a34393238360d0a34383430370d0a31333330350d0a3336340d0a36323735340d0a32313438310d0a35323734350d0a31303931310d0a34323835380d0a373731370d0a34393530320d0a35313034380d0a36323832330d0a34343833370d0a36313934300d0a33393137310d0a33333032320d0a32333836360d0a36313335360d0a31393038380d0a35393135340d0a36353335320d0a32343233300d0a32303936310d0a34313134330d0a35343433350d0a36343038380d0a35323334340d0a33373136370d0a32363734390d0a36353439300d0a36353236360d0a36313234320d0a33343933360d0a313532360d0a35313236310d0a33353039350d0a36303931350d0a34313336350d0a32333235370d0a333133350d0a33373433380d0a34363837350d0a363831390d0a34373034320d0a31373035380d0a363734350d0a35313135340d0a333535330d0a33343134320d0a36353334360d0a34343334310d0a35333330370d0a35333232320d0a34313336300d0a33383037300d0a32363134350d0a34343532310d0a34373836360d0a34393033360d0a36323037320d0a34373630330d0a34363337300d0a34303534360d0a31393231330d0a373930340d0a393839340d0a31383337350d0a35383231360d0a33353033380d0a31333338310d0a32313637350d0a33383333370d0a35393430340d0a31333933300d0a31353830370d0a33373434370d0a31313832370d0a34383331360d0a32393433350d0a32363831360d0a36313035360d0a34303533350d0a33383335340d0a31373037370d0a34383236360d0a31363237350d0a34343331370d0a35343836320d0a34303730370d0a32363735370d0a32353438380d0a3737320d0a32363038330d0a32373339370d0a35323934380d0a34313537340d0a32363934310d0a3433353539

So I need that each entry will be separated and displayed as a list in my output file. If I do have the line

```
for c in out:
print(c)
```

I get the huge list with two decimals in each of it and seemed to be wrong. Please post any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it is using `hex` like so:

```
filename = '1.txt' 
newfile  = '2.txt'

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    numbers = f.read().splitlines() 

with open(newfile, 'w') as n:
    for num in numbers:
        n.write('{}\n'.format(hex(int(num))))
```

Comment: so when I run your code I am getting error                            
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\convert_to_hex.py", line 51, in <module>
    n.write('{}\n'.format(hex(int(num))))
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: what is your python version? Also does your file contains also empty lines or other stuff?

Comment: I have 2.7 and 3 and it does not work in either one and no, there is no empty stuff, only 128 16bit values in decimal format.

Comment: Yeah. It worked now. Is there also a way to get rid of 0x in front of each entry?

Comment: yes, of course, you can write `n.write(hex(int(num))[2:]+'\n')`

Comment: @DanF. you're getting that `0x` because it's trying to encode an empty string (this is what `splitlines()` does to lines that contain only a newline (`\n`). I would just check for the existence of your `num`

Comment: @wpercy Oh ok, got you. But I think the above comment solves the solution as well.

Comment: that's fine, but you shouldn't just be blindly stripping out the first two characters of a line...

Comment: @wpercy I know it's generally unstable - but in the special case of a hex number the `0x` is kind of a standard prefix